# I want to set the print area of a sheet to nothing without having to hiding the sheet

Tags: excel

I have a document that I print out regularly and have a version control page that I don't want to include within it.

Does anyone have a way of doing this short of hiding the sheet or printing sheets 2-10?

I'd ideally not like to use VBA but will if needs be.

Thanks

Update

This has been marked as duplicate but as per above, I don't want to use VBA so I am looking for an alternative solution to the other question. Thanks

Comment: you mean instead of using the "print pages x to x" function build into excel?

Comment: It is possible to print between specific ranges, but you would need to create a macro for that in vba

Comment: Thanks, as I suspected. I wanted an easy print button without having to hide the sheet everytime. I also need to save as pdf without the extra sheet so was trying to avoid that.